# Visual Studio intellisense - RequireJS - upper limit for script loaders reached

Tags: visual-studio, requirejs, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I am struggling with getting VS2015 intellisense to work for my requirejs based app.

I followed this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/04/20/using-requirejs-with-visual-studio.aspx plus some assorted tips from various forums.

I have now gotten so far as to actually make VS realise there are script loader calls in my files.

In the output from the Javascript Language Service the first line indicates that require.config.js has been loaded.

However. As soon as I start typing in one of my module files, the output window is filled with lines like this:

```
File C:\repository\...\invoices.js contains a script loader file reference
(url = ../services/formvalidator.js, type = text/javascript) that will be 
ignored because the upper limit (50) of references that can be added via 
script loaders has been reached.
```

...and intellisense just gives me "Intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression" on all referenced modules.

What do I do now? Surely the whole point of using something like requirejs is to split your code up into separate module files. But if some limit is reached, and no intellisense can be loaded, it seems useless...

Can I change this limit?
Or is something else wrong?

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Cheers!
Kim